# Using SQL to make specific changes in a database.

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out some commands/code in SQL.

I have  database with names, addresses IDs etc, but I have to convert firstname values ending in “jnr” to “(Jnr)” and those ending in “snr” to “(Snr)”.

How do I do this?

Comment: do you want to this when the data is inserted? or do you have data already stored that you wished to be modified?

Comment: Use [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) with a string replace function

Comment: I have used the follwoing code for a previous line - SELECT `lastname` FROM `coursework final` WHERE `lastname` LIKE 'O   %' OR `lastname` LIKE 'Mc %';       UPDATE `coursework final` set lastname = REPLACE (lastname, 'o ', 'O\''); - But I am not sure how to adapt it for the other changes. The data is already stored, so the changes are made after.

Comment: paste(column, CHAR_LENGTH(column)-3, 3, 'Jnr') where column like '%jnr'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update table TABLE_NAME set NAMES = '*xyz*Jnr' where NAMES like '%jnr'`

Comment: `%` matches `varchar` values with `zero or more characters` and `jnr` will constraint the ending 3 letters of the `varchar`.

Comment: `*xyz*` , can be anything that goes before `Jnr`. whatever that you want.

Comment: You mean everybody with a name ending with jnr will have the name xyzJnr after the update. I'm not sure that's what OP asked for...

Answer (score 0):

Update or select:

```
PASTE(column, CHAR_LENGTH(column)-3, 1, UPPER(SUBSTRING(column FROM CHAR_LENGTH(column)-3 FOR 1)
WHERE column LIKE '%jnr' OR column LIKE '%snr'
```

`PASTE` is used to put in one character at position 3 from end,
`CHAR_LENGTH` to get length of column value,
`UPPER` converts character to upper case,
`SUBSTRING` is used to pick one character here (j or s),
`LIKE` is used to find values ending with jnr, or snr.

All ANSI SQL (no dbms specified!)